# Mongoengine: update only specified fields on embedded document

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have the following schema:

```
class Task(EmbeddedDocument):
    description = StringField()
    is_finished = BooleanField(default=False)

class Plan(DynamicDocument):
    priority = IntField()
    tasks = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Task)
```

Then I create a plan instance from dictionary (originally I'm getting the dictionary from json body of http request):

```
body = {"priority": 1, "tasks": [{"description": "do this", "is_finished": true}]}

plan = Plan(**body).save()
```

Then I'm trying to update `description` of the task embedded document while leaving its other field `is_finished` unchanged and also leaving `priority` field of plan unchanged:

```
new_body = {"tasks": [{"description": "do that"}]}
plan.update(**new_body)
```

However after the update `is_finished` value changes to `false` (it's default value).

```
print(plan.to_json())
# prints {"priority": 1, "tasks": [{"description": "do that", "is_finished": false}]}
```

How can I update document while keeping unspecified embedded fields unchanged just like I did with `priority` field on main document? I tried removing default value from embedded document model but then I just drops the field completely if it's not specified during update.

Answer (score 1):

This will update the specific field

```
plan.update(set__tasks__0__description='your new description')
```

Here, 0 is the ordinality of the Embedded Document (in the list 'tasks') whose description you want to update.